# Accessing resources from the maven archetype's resources folder programmatically from the script archetype-post-generate.groovy

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

The post-generation mechanism in maven relies on the script archetype-post-generate.groovy. The script itself is located in the src/main/resources/META-INF folder of the archetype project. If I include other resources in the src/main/resources folder, can I access them programmatically from the archetype-post-generate.groovy script? Can I for example read and parse the text file which is located in the src/main/resources folder?

I know that it's technically possible to find and extract the archetype jar file in the local .m2 repository but I am looking for a more elegant solution which wouldn't include that.